# Why isn't it working for "not xy balanced"?

Tags: java

We'll say that a String is xy-balanced if for all the 'x' chars in the string, there exists a 'y' char somewhere later in the string. So "xxy" is balanced, but "xyx" is not. One 'y' can balance multiple 'x's. Given a string str, Print “xy balanced”if the given string is xy-balanced otherwise print “not xy balanced”.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    String str = scan.next();
    int x = str.length();
    boolean xyBalanced = false;

    for(int i = x - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        char y = str.charAt(i);

        if(y == 'y')
            xyBalanced = true;

        else if(y == 'x')
            xyBalanced = false;

        else
            xyBalanced = true;
    }

    if(xyBalanced = true)
        System.out.print("xy balanced");

    else if(xyBalanced = false)
        System.out.print("not xy balanced");
}
```

It's giving me "xy balanced" when I input aabbx when in fact it should give "not xy balanced". What is wrong with this code?

Comment: `if(xyBalanced = true)` should probably be `if(xyBalanced == true)` or even better: `if(xyBalanced)`. Same for the else if.

Comment: How is `xxy` balanced? There are two `x`(s) and only one `y`.

Comment: Also, if your logic is correct, then it could be just `return str.lastIndexOf('y') > str.lastIndexOf('x');`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I think you mean str.lastIndexOf('x') < (str.length()-1)

Comment: the question says that only one y is enough to balance as many x chars as there are as long as they're on the left side of the y char.

Comment: @ergonaut As long as `y` is after `x` it's balanced. Nothing about the end of the `String`.

Comment: use `==` for comparison. When you put `xyBalanced = true` you're *setting* `xyBalanced` to true rather than *comparing* it to true.

Comment: you can do following for identifying balanced string

boolean xyBalanced = inputString.lastIndexOf('x') < (inputString.indexOf('y')-1);

Answer (score 1):

Why do you check from the end of the string to the start? It is very difficult to understand.

Apart from the if/else issue you have at the end of your program, which you can change to below, your program still doesn't work after I corrected it.

```
System.out.print(xyBalanced ? "xy balanced" : "not xy balanced");
```

To check if there is always a 'y' on the right of an 'x', you can use the following loop - basically, an 'x' always set the xyBalanced flag to false and a 'y' always set it to be true.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    String str = scan.next();
    int length = str.length();
    boolean xyBalanced = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == 'x') {
            xyBalanced = false;
        } else if (str.charAt(i) == 'y') {
            xyBalanced = true;
        }
    }

    System.out.print(xyBalanced ? "xy balanced" : "not xy balanced");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement:

```
if(xyBalanced = true)
```

Is an assignment operator, it should be using the == operator:

```
if(xyBalanced == true){
    System.out.print("xy balanced");
} else {
    System.out.print("not xy balanced");
}
```

Since it's a boolean you can also say:

```
System.out.print( (!xyBalanced? "not" : "") + "xy balanced");
```

However, from your logic, it seems like you can also say

```
boolean xyBalanced = str.lastIndexOf('x') < (str.length()-1);
```

Because you are considering non-x/non-y characters.

So really you can simplify all the code into two lines.

Also there is an issue with your loop.  You're actually going from the right to left. Is that intentional?

```
for(int i = x - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

would seem like it should be:

```
for (int i=0;i<x;i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do following for identifying balanced string

```
boolean xyBalanced = inputString.lastIndexOf('x') < inputString.indexOf('y');
```

indexOf function always returns first occurrence of string. We can check if last index of x is less than first index of y, and variable 'xyBalanced' will be accordingly get true or false.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean xyBalance(String str) {
if(str.endsWith("x")){
System.out.println("false");
return false;
}
if(str.endsWith("y")){ 
System.out.println("true");
return true;
}
if(str.lastIndexOf("x")>str.lastIndexOf("y")) {
System.out.println("false");
return false;
}
System.out.println("true");
return true;
}
```

Comment: you should add an explanation with your answer.